# WCF Service Windows Authentication Not Working

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7.5

I have changed Web.Config and the service is working with Anonymous Authentication. Though when Windows Authentication is enabled and Anonymous Authentication is disabled in IIS7.5, it starts giving me following error. Please help.

> The authentication schemes configured on the host
>   ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on
>   the binding 'basicHTTP' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the
>   SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly. 
>   Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication
>   schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through
>   the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the
>   application configuration file at the 
>   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
>   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.

Web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="JSONBinding"></binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHTTP">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>     
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="JSON">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
<service name="RestWCFService.CalculationService" behaviorConfiguration="basicBehavior">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="RestWCFService.ICalculatorService" bindingName ="basicHTTP"></endpoint>
  <!--    
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="JSON" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="JSONBinding" contract="RestWCFService.ICalculatorService" name="JSONService"></endpoint>
  -->
  </service>      
</services>

<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"   />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You are not using your basic HTTP binding named `basicHTTP` in the endpoint. Change the attribute in your endpoint from `bindingName="basicHTTP"` to `bindingConfiguration="basicHTTP"`.

By the way it could be that you have to enable both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication in IIS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing stuff with bindingConfiguration. Changing it lead to another Windows Authentication Error. Though in Windows Authentication don't we need to disable anonymous? Error is: The extended protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the transport.  The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  IIS has a value of Always while the WCF Transport has a value of Never.

Comment: Basically the error is happening due to IIS7.5 Windows Authentication with Extended Protection which is set to Required/Always with me. Thanks anyways for making me come out of earlier error. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Need to add additional parameters <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="WhenSupported"></extendedProtectionPolicy>  in <transport> tag. Thanks.